# Catastrophic backtracking for largetext

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have regular expression to allow alphanumeric, comma(,) and FullStop(.) and for small words (like 10 characters) it is working fine. But for big words around 850 characters the application is hanging.

Below is my regex expression.

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+[\s,])*\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1}\.{0,1}$/
```

Some example text:

> Excellent communication skills, Currently working with Infosys as
>   member L and D team,Conducts V and A trainings, process trainings for
>   new hires, involves in call monitoring, soft skill, email etiquettes
>   training Identifies training needs and prepare action plans and is
>   involved in preparing training contents,Has experience managing
>   Competency Based training calendar each month across verticals,Very
>   energetic, sincere and has right attitude towards career,Confident in
>   her approach and has clear aspirations,Conversation and very good at
>   listening,Seems to be a team player and believes in taking extra
>   initiatives,Recommending a bit higher salary as she is going through
>   her appraisals.Good education background, scored first class
>   throughout,Very stable candidate working with Infosys since more than
>   5 years

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Please provide some text input. Eventually, you could use anchors to let the regex engine come to an end (and fail) faster. Additionally, nested quantifiers (like your `+`, followed by a `*`) are often the cause of catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Jan I added the texts in two comments as it is not allowing to enter in one try.

Comment: Edited your question and changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested quantifiers and the fact that the same `\s` can be matched in many different ways by the regex open it up to catastrophic backtracking. Also, some simplifications are possible.

The following fails a lot faster:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\s,]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?$
```

This matches a sentence of one or more alphanumeric words, separated by whitespace and/or commas, with an optional final period. The text you posted as a test subject fails because there is a period in the middle which is not allowed by the regex. If you want to allow periods there as well, just add it to the character class:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\s,.]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?$
```

Comment: I am new to regx. Could you please provide complete regx here?